# Show list of items and when they are more than 2 show mat-menu instead

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I have an array of items. I want to show these items and when they are more than two, a button will show up instead with the number of the remaining items and their name.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
        <div>
            <div class="avatar" *ngIf=" i<2" />
              {{items.Name}}
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="i >= 2 && items?.length > 2">
               <button class="avatar" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">+ {{items?.length-2}}</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{items.Name}}</button>
            </mat-menu>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

My problems:

- the button with the number of the rest of the items shows more than once since it is under ngFor, and I need the ngFor to show the item.Name, how to fix that?
- is there a better way to display the number of the rest of items instead of
   `+ {{items?.length-2}}`

Comment: Hey! I don't know if I understood your question correctly... So you want to show all the items in the array, if the array has more than 1 item you want to have a button. Is this correct?

Comment: @MrRobot  Hey MrRobot! I see my question is not really clear. If they are more than two, I want to show the first two in an horizontal line and then a mat-button(contains the number of the rest of the items, if they are four it will contain +2) whenever we click it, it shows a tooltip containing the rest of the items

Answer (score 0):

you have to choice:
1-

```html
<div *ngIf="i == 2 && items?.length > 2">
               <button class="avatar" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">+ {{items?.length-2}}</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{items.Name}}</button>
            </mat-menu>
```

2- move button to outside of for and change it to :

```html
<div *ngIf="items?.length > 2">
               <button class="avatar" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">+ {{items?.length-2}}</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
              <button mat-menu-item>{{items.Name}}</button>
            </mat-menu>
```